# Composite JSF component with converter

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, converters, composite-component

I have composite JSF component `TimePicker.xhtml` with a backing component `timePickerComponent` which is used as below:

```
      <mi:timePicker style="display: initial;"
        widgetVar="toTimepickerWidget"
        converter="#{timePickerConverter}"
                            value="#{calendarBean.event.to}" 
      />
```

And `timePickerConverter` created in usual way:

```
public class TimePickerConverter implements Converter, Serializable {
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, String arg2)
            throws ConverterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1, Object arg2)
            throws ConverterException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return null;
    }
}
```

How can I use this converter in composite component?

**UPDATE:**

This is code of the Composite Component:

```
<cc:implementation componentType="timePickerComponent">
    <h:outputScript name="js/timepicker/timepicker_helper.js" target="head"/>
    <div id="#{cc.clientId}" style="#{cc.attrs.style}">

            <p:inputText id="timepicker"
                    scrollHeight="200"
                    value="#{cc.timeLocal}"  
                    size="5"/>

    </div>
</cc:implementation>
```

Basically what do I want is to convert plain text from `inputText` to `Date` object. Date's part irrelevant for me, I only need Time's part of the object.
Btw, as a temporary solution I'll use `getConvertedValue` as described in this article from **BalusC** [Composite component with multiple input fields](http://balusc.blogspot.co.il/2013/01/composite-component-with-multiple-input.html)But would like to know how to delegate this functionality to an external converter too, as described in the article

> Normally this method is not to be overridden and everything is
>   delegated to default JSF Converter mechanisms

Comment: Can you add the `TimePicker.xhtml`? And where's your actual problem?

Comment: @Smutje, due to company limitation I can't post exact code snippet so I posted MVCE with the same idea, thank you.

Comment: I don't quite understand, why don't you supply the converter to the `inputText` similar to `<p:inputText id="timepicker" ... converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}"/>`

Comment: @Smutje, if we're talking about **simple** composite component it's possible of course, but if we're talking about composite component with multiple input fields? Multiple  `<p:inputText>`? In this case only **delegated converter** can be a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to use converters you can invoke converter explicitly in your backing component in method `getConvertedValue`. The converter could be retrieved from component's `converter` attribute:

```
@FacesComponent("timePickerComponent")
public class TimePickerComponent extends UIInput implements NamingContainer {

    ...

    @Override
    public Object getSubmittedValue() {
        UIInput hourComp = (UIInput) findComponent("timepicker_hour");
        UIInput minutesComp = (UIInput) findComponent("timepicker_minutes");
        return hourComp.getSubmittedValue() + ":" + minutesComp.getSubmittedValue();
    }

    @Override
    protected Object getConvertedValue(FacesContext context,
            Object newSubmittedValue) throws ConverterException {
        Converter converter = (Converter) getAttributes().get("converter");
        if (converter != null) {
            return converter.getAsObject(context, this, (String) newSubmittedValue);
        } else {
            return newSubmittedValue;
        }
    }

}
```

See example code:
https://github.com/destin/SO-answers/tree/master/SO-composite-jsf-component-with-converter

However, drawback of this method is that JSF components convert from String. As I understand your component consists of few subelements. All their values needs to be converted to string (like I did: `hourComp.getSubmittedValue() + ":" + minutesComp.getSubmittedValue()`).

So maybe you would prefer to define your own hierarchy if TimeConverters independent of JSF components. Such converters would be able to use few parameters or some complex object (like `Time`) as a source. Such converters could be retrieved in exactly the same way as I did.